# Measure LCP and FCP before deployment jenkins

Tags: performance, jenkins, deployment, next.js, core-web-vitals

I am looking for a way to measure largest contentful paint (LCP) and first contentful paint (FCP) before deployment in jenkins, and some way where i can set the performance budget for lcp and fcp and if the website exceeds that budget an email should be sent and deployment should be stop.

Can anyone please explain if this is possible and under what circumstances it will?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lighthouse, which has a way to set [performance budgets](https://web.dev/use-lighthouse-for-performance-budgets/). It looks like there's a [Lighthouse plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lighthouse-report/), but I haven't used it before and it may not be compatible with the budget feature.